# How to know my lighting shaders matches famous models?

Tags: unity, shaders

I have some diffuse and specular lighting shaders based on famous models like lambert etc. Thing is, how can I know that my shader is actually implementing the correct formula? I can see my materials does reflect light but how can I be sure that my formula matches the models. Any way to test this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a well known software that implements it correctly (such as [Marmoset Toolbag](https://www.marmoset.co/toolbag/)) and compare its rendering of your object with your own renderer. If there is no difference, you know you've done it right.